# readen words from a file have bigger lenght than the real one

Tags: php, file, extract

i extract a text from a .txt with file() but the lenght of the words (strlen) is bigger with 2, except the last word;
eg: if my words.txt looks like this :

> sql
>
> word
>
> php

strlen(sql) = 5

strlen(word) = 6

strlen(php) = 3

Why? thx

Answer (score 0):

Probably because of the line ending "\n" at the end of each line. Can you provide the code for reading the file in order to help you better?

To remove all newlines and carriage returns, use this code:

```
$val = preg_replace('/\r|\n/', '', $val);
```

Comment: `while($word)
 {
  $file = file("words.txt");
  foreach ($file as $key => $val) {
   echo $word . " " . $val . "<br>";
   echo strlen($word) . " " . strlen($val). "<br>";
   if($val == $word)
    #code
  }
  $word = strtok(" ");
 }` //i have a variable $text with a text, thats why i use strtok

Comment: I updated my answer, you should remove the newlines and carriage returns first, before counting the length of each line.

Answer (score 0):

`strlen()` returns the number of bytes rather than the number of characters in a string.
try using `mb_strlen()` instead